# Unable to deploy custom helm chart in GKE, no pods created

Tags: kubernetes

I have [Helm 3](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-3-released/) and `gcloud` installed on my local (Windows) machine, and I am able to access my GKE clusters using `kubectl` command.

I have gone through several tutorials and I am able to install Helm charts from public repository, but when I try to deploy my custom helm charts (available on my local machine) using this command `helm install <my_custom_chartname> .`

The pods don't come up in the cluster, however I get a success message every time also it creates the service defined in the chart.

Am I missing something?